signal issue in nx angular monorepo shared service
I have a angular NX monorepo, created few libs & applications, created a lib for shared service named theme
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeService {
  themeSignal = signal<string>('light');

  setTheme(theme: string) {
    this.themeSignal.set(theme);
  }
}

in one of the library I have toggle functionality to change theme
toggleTheme() {
    this.themeService.themeSignal.update(value => value==='light'?'dark':'light');
    console.log(this.themeService.themeSignal())
  }

and trying to access updated signal in two applications in ngAfterViewInit as below
console.log(this.themeService.themeSignal())
in the application themeSignal is not getting triggered, but in toggleTheme function I can see it is getting updated

I suppose you trigger theme change when your components are already being rendered.
And by using ngAfterViewInit you will see console log of theme value that was at the time components being appeared on the screen.
Try logging theme value in template so that you will be able to see runtime value, also you can use .subscribe method on signal to see it's changing or not.
Need a bit more details for sure and better a stackblitz example. Pretty sure you will be able to make a reproduction with using only sibling components. There is nothing to do with nx here
